# Titanium mobile installed package size is too large

Tags: mobile, titanium

I have made a very simple game in titanium mobile. I only use 90k of sound files, but use quite a lot of graphics, so my `.apk` file is about 2.5MB. I am guessing most of this comes from the graphics files. I have a couple of specific questions.

1. Does the size of graphics files that are not used get added to final package?
   (I am guessing yes, because compiler can not execute dynamic javascript to figure out if file could ever be needed)
2. Does the size of graphics files in the Resources/iphone folder affect the size of the android package (and visa versa)
3. Are the packages bigger on average than using native code alone? If so, by how much?
4. What else can I do to reduce the package size?
5. What method of compressing images is most successful on android phone?
6. What size for a file do people consider normal? (when should I stop trying to optimise?)

So basically, how do I measure and reduce the size of the components and final deliverable package?

Comment: 2.5MB is pretty reasonable, if you ask me.

Comment: As @ceejayoz said, 2.5 is pretty reasonable. I think it is small for a game. If you take a look at the average game it can easily go over 20MB. Unfortunately I do not have all the answers for you

Comment: My game is incredibly simple, has two screens, and about a hundred lines of code. I have had feedback that this is large enough that it will put off some people from installing in a limited space. I have seen other games that are slightly more complex than mine, that have installed footprint of less than 500 k. I want to know if it is possible to achieve this with Titanium.

Comment: Probably not. There's overhead to using non-native code and an interpreter like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer questions 1, 2, 4 & 6:

1) Yes - unused graphics are added to the final package.

2) No - the Resources/iphone graphics are not included.

You can see the intermediate (pre-apk) by looking at `build/android/bin/assets/Resources` to see what is being compiled into your binary.

4) You could try [minifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) the JS files.

6) IMO 2.5MB is pretty small

Answer (score 1):

i tried to answer a few questions:

1. i think so since the matching splashscreen should be loaded depending on the screen resolution of the device. so you need to have an image in different resolutions in stock.
2. packages should be [zipalign](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/zipalign.html). to check your apk use

   zipalign -c -v  existing.apk
3. 2.5mb is not as big as i might think. many apps are >10 mb.. so no one will be confused about your app size.

try a look [in the android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unused libraries.

1. Unzip the apk
2. go to the /lib directory.
3. you will find 3 subdirectories:
   **armeabi**
   **armeabi-v7a**
   **x86**

now you can create 3 deployments this three above named plattforms.